# how to remove timer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have this timer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimerFunc) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and on some function i want to completly remove this...how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use NSTimer in Cocos2d, instead you should do:

```
[self schedule:@selector(updateTimerFunc) interval:1.0];
```

And to remove it:

```
[self unschedule:@selector(updateTimerFunc)];
```

or:

```
[self unscheduleAllSelectors];
```

If you have an update-function you could use: `[self scheduleUpdate];`